Dynamic import using defined aliases
Is it possible to use Nuxt aliases inside a dynamic import? What I'm trying to do is have a plugin with a dynamic import in a base layer and have it import the files relative to the currently running project extending that layer. However, the dynamic import is relative to the layer it is used in.
Consider the following example project:
base/
 - app/
    - plugins/
       - dynamic.ts
    - utils/
       - general.ts
 // ...

project/
 - app/
    - utils/
       - general.ts
 // ...

When I use the following static import in the base layer:
// base/app/plugins/dynamic.ts
import { foo } from '@/utils/general'

and I run the dev server in project/, the function will be imported from project/app/utils/general.ts instead of base/app/utils/general.ts.
How can I achieve this behaviour with a dynamic import?
Something like:
() => import(`@/dynamic-pages/${pageName}.vue`) // does not work

I tried using await resolvePath('@/dynamic-pages') utility from @nuxt/kit, but Vite isn't able to analyze the dynamic import when used like this.
